# What happened to the other personalities of the Greek Gods in Percy Jackson?

Tags: percy-jackson

In the universe that Rick Riordan created he includes Greek gods, Egyptian gods, Viking gods, and Roman gods. As we find out in [The Heroes of Olympus](https://www.goodreads.com/series/51379-the-heroes-of-olympus) series, the Roman gods are only varied personalities/manifestations of the Greek gods. After Rome had fallen the gods moved to the most influentially powerful  place on Earth at the time (Germany, England etc...).  We also see that the locations appear to affect the Greek manifestations of the gods.

Why don't the locations affect the personalities/manifestations of the Roman gods?

Answer (score 4):

The fact that the Roman gods are just modified versions of the Greek gods is not something Riordan made up. That is exactly how the Roman pantheon was created. The fact his fictional gods then moved to other places has no impact on their personalities, because while they may have moved, they were no longer worshipped in new aspects, but rather in their old ones:

Their Greek (and Roman) aspects are continued to be (unconsciously) worshipped, e.g. by building huge halls with columns reminiscent of Ancient Greece and maybe putting a huge sitting statue of a powerful figure in it (Zeus vs. President Lincoln, maybe?).

[image: Zeus] [image: Lincoln]

After the Fall of Rome, no *new* aspects were added personality-wise, although the gods (both their Greek and their Roman aspects) became more modern in Riordan's works, with regard to tools and appearance, but that is just the *Mist*, really; it did not create any *new* aspects.

(Both statue pictures come from their respective wikipedia pages)

Answer (score 1):

They are "in" them, we just haven't seen that side of them yet.
Like in the PJ series that we only deal with Greek gods, it wasn't until the "Heroes of Olympus" that we see the Roman side of Zeus ( errr... Jupiter ).

Answer (score -1):

In HOO, Thalia says something about how Zeus behaved differently around the time that Jason(a son of Jupiter) was conceived, indicating they do have different behaviour. In addition, Athena was made less warlike and more homely by the Romans.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I'm just trying to interpret the question, but I think the question isn't about the Greek and Roman aspects being different, the question is why, when other powers arose after the fall of Rome, the Roman gods retained their essential aspects and weren't further modified.